# How to disable GET Logout in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is it possible to get rid of GET /auth/logout = getLogoutR? or change its behavior? similar to the loginHandler in the YesodAuth

Basically, I want to prevent somebody to send a link to naive users that will logout them.

Answer (score 4):

One thing (not tested) which will likely work is adding a definition for it in the `Yesod` instance. Something like this:

```
instance Yesod App where

    isAuthorized (AuthR LogoutR) False = return $ Unauthorized "must be admin"
```

The `False` is to make sure that it will only operate on `GET` request.

Comment: Good enough for my case :)